# Запрос по форме в access

Tags: база-данных, access

Здравствуйте,
В Access есть форма с несколькими полями и кнопка при нажатии на которую, формируется запрос к таблице. Получается, что поля все обязательные если указать в условии отбора просто поле формы. Не могу додуматься как правильно сделать так, чтобы искал только по введенным данным, а пустые поля не трогал.
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В условии отбора указывалось поле `[Формы]![Выборка по записям]![Поле0])`, как не пробовал единственный правильный вариант который работает с необязательными полями выглядит так

```
IIf(IsNull([Формы]![Выборка по записям]![Поле0]);[Автомобили]![Штатный номер авто];[Формы]![Выборка по записям]![Поле0])
```

Знаю, что простая фигня, но намучился по всякому